# Automatically fill function arguments

Tags: javascript, java, android, html

in java and in android studio when we write a function like this:

```
function test (View v) { ... }
```

and put it in xml layout

```
<TextView
 android:onclick="test" />
```

v as an argument filled automatically by java and when we click at that TextView v filled with property of that TextView clicked on

how can I define this in javascript and html tags ?

Thanks.

Comment: huh? you want javascript to work like java? I don't think javascript needs to take a backward step like that

Comment: It's not actually filled by "Java". There is a great deal of underlying machinery in Android system that makes it work like it does. Now, in HTML there is indeed a similar mechanism - when you define the event listener function on an element, it receives the element which raised an event as argument into a function - to allow you to hook the same event listener function with multiple DOM elements.

Comment: ... however, I can't understand your question. Are you asking about HTML pages in general? Or HTML pages that would be rendered on Android devices? Or linking some Android Activity method as an event listener in page opened via WebView? What are the `java` and `android` tags for? What is the actual problem you're solving?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```js
function myFunction(element) {
  element.innerHTML = "hello";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction(this)">Click me</button>
```

Pass the clicked element that is stored in `this` as a parameter to the click function.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to add the "this" keyword, "this" keyword automatically gets the action of the current element if it clicked, checked, etc in cases of buttons, check-boxes, respectively...

I totally agree with Costin here.

HTML :

```
<button id="btn" onclick="someFunction(this)">Tap It</button>
```

JS:

```
function someFunction(element) {
  element.innerHTML = "hello";
}
```

which means the someFunction will automatically get that the element is "button" here and on its click, the action needs to be performed is to change its HTML and display "hello".